# Inner join with increased value on its duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, row-number

**UPDATED**
I have 3 Tables like this:

```
[dbo].[CHEQUES]:
|Cla_Pdv    |    Che    |    Fecha    |    Tur    |
---------------------------------------------------       
|   FUEM    |    4423   |2016-01-01   |     2     |
--------------------------------------------------- 

[dbo].[CAPMO]:
|Clave_Pdv    |    Che    |    Com    |    Pla    |    Descripcion    |    Precio    |    Can    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
|   FUEM      |     4423  |      1    |    184    |    POZ            |    85        |    1    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     4423  |      2    |    184    |    POZ            |    85        |    1    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     4423  |      3    |    184    |    POZ            |    84        |    1    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[dbo].[TURNO]:
|Clave_Pdv    |    Tur    |    Descripcion    |
-----------------------------------------------     
|   FUEM      |     1     |      DESAYUNOS    |
-----------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     2     |      COMIDAS      |
-----------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     3     |      CENAS        |
-----------------------------------------------
```

i need each value of the [dbo].[Capmo] table but i want to increase the quantity of the first row since two rows have the same value on the column 'Pla' gettting and output like this:

```
|  Cheque  |  Turno    |  Clave_Pdv  |  Pla  |  Descripcion  |  Precio  |  Cantidad  |
|   4423   |  COMIDAS  |    FUEM     |  184  |       POZ     |    85    |      2     |
|   4423   |  COMIDAS  |    FUEM     |  184  |       POZ     |    84    |      1     |
```

Comment: Join the 2 tables based on their FK, then group on all the fields in your result except the last, use a SUM(Can)

Comment: i used a left join and got the result then i group by like this:group by  [dbo].[CHEQUES].Fecha,[dbo].[TURNOS].Descripcion,  [dbo].[CHEQUES].Che, [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV,[dbo].[CAPMO].Pla,[dbo].[CAPMO].Descripcion,[dbo].[CAPMO].Precio_Neto, but i dont know how to add the Sum(CAn) how do i make it?

Comment: added like this at last on the group by but i keep getting an error
sum([dbo].[CAPMO].Can)

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to actually need a join between `Cheques` and `Capmo` as your output can be obtained from `Capmo` However, you mention other tables in your comment, you might want to expand your question to include a complete example.

### Data

```
SELECT * INTO Cheques FROM (
  VALUES('FUEM', 4423, '2016-01-01', 2)) A (Cla_Pdv, Che, Fecha, Tur)


SELECT * INTO Capmo FROM (
  VALUES
  ('FUEM', 4423, 1, 184, 'POZ', 85, 1)
  ,('FUEM', 4423, 2, 184, 'POZ', 85, 1)
  ,('FUEM', 4423, 3, 184, 'POZ', 84, 1)
  ) A (Clave_pdv, Che, Com, Pla, Descripcion, Precio, Can)

SELECT * INTO Turno FROM (
  VALUES
  ('FUEM', 1,'DESAYUNOS')
  ,('FUEM', 2,'COMIDAS')
  ,('FUEM', 3,'CENAS')
  ) A (Clave_pdv, Tur,Descripcion)
```

### Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Cheques.Che Cheque
    ,Turno.Descripcion Turno
   ,Capmo.Clave_Pdv
   ,Capmo.Pla
   ,Capmo.Descripcion
   ,Capmo.Precio
   ,SUM(Capmo.Can) OVER ( PARTITION BY Capmo.Precio ) Cantidad
FROM
    Capmo
    JOIN Cheques ON Capmo.Clave_pdv = Cheques.Cla_pdv
    JOIN Turno ON Capmo.Clave_pdv = Turno.Clave_pdv AND Cheques.Tur = Turno.Tur
    ORDER BY Precio DESC;

Cheque      Turno     Clave_Pdv Pla         Descripcion Precio      Cantidad
----------- --------- --------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
4423        COMIDAS   FUEM      184         POZ         85          2
4423        COMIDAS   FUEM      184         POZ         84          1

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: thanks for the anwser @Les H i just updated the question to add the third row i need in my output, your query make the output i want but i stil need to make a join between a the [dbo].[Turno] but everytime i make a join with it it multiply my result to more than the two rows i need how can i do this?

Comment: @ArturoMartinez I've updated the answer - I think this is what you're looking for (although you haven't really defined your primary keys or foreign key relationships)

Comment: i just tryed your query with the correct results but my 'Cantidad' value is not correct i get the output 1951 and 486 on my Cantidad column